# OS X: fsck_hfs unable to fix volume directory count

Tags: macos, fsck, hfs+

I'm running `fsck_hfs` on a very large volume. Unfortunately, there's an issue it appears to be unable to fix -- it reports it, loops back to start with `Rechecking...`, and reports it again, ad infinitum.

```
** Checking catalog hierarchy.
   Invalid volume directory count
   (It should be 513997 instead of 513998)
   Incorrect folder count in a directory (id = 27444570)
   (It should be 1 instead of 0)
```

I've tried adding the `-r` ("rebuild catalog btree") flag to fsck, but the issue still recurs.

Answer (score 3):

The volume is probably locked, so you should retry what you are doing after booting into either the Recovery HD parition (Command-R while booting) or with a OS X install CD.

Comment: Checking the mount table, the volume is certainly not mounted anywhere (not even read-only).